# ¿Por qué aparece automaticamente estos simbolos extraños cuando estoy escribiendo codigo en java con Netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

[image: Error]

Cuando estoy escribiendo esta instrucción sencilla para imprimir un "Hola Mundo" me aparece automáticamente esos símbolos como de una x pequeña y unos dos puntos justamente después del primer paréntesis y antes de las primeras comillas. No afectan la compilación en absoluto, pero quisiera saber a que se debe ya que en varios tutoriales que he visto nunca las he visto aparecer.

Aclaro que no las puedo borrar manualmente, solo se desaparecen si quito las comillas o el paréntesis.

Comment: Eso es por el IDE que estás utilizando, la cual te índica que es lo que espera que pases como argumento. Si pruebas a utilizar alguna función que te pida más de un parámetro, verás como te pone algo similar cuando pases los argumentos.

Answer (score 3):

Los IDE como NetBeans e IntelliJ tienen lo que llaman "*hints*" (pistas), que ayudan a saber qué parametros tienes que pasar.

En este caso, puedes ver que el método `println` recibe un parámetro de tipo String que en [la documentación oficial llamaron `x`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.String)):

> `public void println(String x)`
>
> Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as
> though it invokes print(String) and then println().
>
> Parameters:
> **x** - The `String` to be printed.

Otro motivo más por el que es siempre recomendable poner nombres descriptivos a las variables y a los parámetros en tu código. En este caso particular no tiene importancia, pero imagina que tienes un método para copiar ficheros:

```
copiarFichero(File a, File b) {...}
```

Algo así no ayuda mucho, pero si lo declaras como

```
copiarFichero(File origen, File destino) { ... }
```

en ese caso el desarrollador, con los *hints* que le muestra el IDE sabe el orden correcto en el que debe poner los parámetros sin tener que mirar documentación o el código, ya que vería algo como

```
File o = ...
File d = ...
copiarFichero(origen:o,destino:d);
```

Recuerda que esos *hints* no son parte del código y en el caso de que te molesten (por ejemplo, hacen que las líneas de código se vean más largas de lo que realmente son y en algunos casos eso puede ser incómodo) puedes desactivarlos en las preferencias del IDE

Comment: Muchas gracias! De verdad que tu respuesta resolvió mi inquietud a plenitud.